# How to add a mailto to a sentence without extra spacing?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple sentence.

-For further information, email adopt@bc-rescue.com.

I need that sentence to be regular text, non clickable, until i get to "adopt@bc-rescue.com" then i need that to be clickable and open up your email.

I tried coding it like so:

```
<p id="email">For further information, email <a href="adopt@bc-rescue.com">adopt@bc-rescue.com</a>.</p>
```

The problem im having is when i open up the site, there's a huge gap between "email" and "adopt@bc-rescue.com" and it simply doesn't look good. How can i code this without a gap?

Is this something i would do in CSS?

Thanks again!

Comment: `Is this something i would do in CSS` check it for the style for links. There should be no huge gap, it appears due to the applied css styles. ps: `href="mailto:email@address"`

Comment: Without seeing your CSS, we can't answer the question.

Comment: You may have, some where in you css, something similar to `a { margin-left: 10px; }`

Comment: You would probably have some CSS inside your stylesheet defined for anchor tags. You will need to override that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply in-line styling in you anchor tag to remove any margin/padding in your anchor tag:

```
<a style="margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px;" href="adopt@bc-rescue.com">adopt@bc-rescue.com</a>
```

It will help avoid disturbing styling from elsewhere in your page/application.

Comment: I added my <p> and sentence in to this coding, works perfectly now! Thank you so much Tariq!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why thats happening to you, as whenever I try it, it works exactly as you describe it. However, I believe that your problem is your browser.

Though one minor thing:
there is one misplaced period after the < a > (I added a comment where it was)

```
<p id="email">For further information, email <a href="adopt@bc-rescue.com">
adopt@bc-rescue.com</a>.<!--Right here to the left--></p>
```

You can see your code work flawsessly@

http://jsfiddle.net/e66peagc/

Comment: Weird, i dont get it. The period being after the e-mail was in hopes that the period wasn't apart of the link, so i added it after. Who knows, maybe that was what was goofing it? Ty for the response!

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer
I believe your real problem is not seen;I think you may have not closed a tag that you haven't shown us

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail() {
    var text = document.forms["anything"]["email"].value;

    var atpos=text.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=text.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos+2 || dotpos+2 > text.lenght) {  
alert ("please enter valid email address.");
return false;
    }

}
```